# Is it possible to solve this quadratic equation without calculating discriminant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have the quadratic equation $\;\;5x^2+96x-576=0\;\;$. I wonder can we solve it without using formula $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ ? I suspect there is some way to do it because we have a lot of $24$s , ( $96=24\times4$ and $576=24^2)$ but I can't find it.

Comment: $(5x-24)(x+24)$

Comment: @vitamind  but how can I recognize this factoring instantly ?

Comment: The product of $5$ and $-576$ is $-2880$. Factors of $-2880$ which sum to $-96$ are $-24$ and $120$.

Comment: $96=5\cdot 24-24$

Comment: @amirali Its something that comes with practice, something you have to learn, it is not something that can be taught. For example, a good cook can easily eyeball quantities while an amateur has to use measuring cups, yet the good cook will have a hard time teaching the amateur how to effectively eyeball. A good cook has good measurement sense. A good mathematician has good number sense.

Comment: @SomeGuy Thank you for the advises. for this specific factoring, after reading kalashot comment I realized it is not hard to do it. first we write it as $(5x+\quad?\quad)(x+\quad?\quad)$. in order to have $96x$, right question mark should be $24$ and the left one should be $-24$ and we make sure that $24\times-24=-576$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y = 24$ and you have

$$5x^2+4xy - y^2$$

which easily factors as $(5x-y)(x+y)$.

Answer (score 2):

On recognizing that $96=24\cdot4$ and $576=24^2$, it makes sense to let $x=24u$, factor out the $24^2$ from all three terms, and reduce the quadratic to

$$5u^2+4u-1=0$$

This factors easily into $(5u-1)(u+1)=0$, at which point you can let $u=x/24$, multiply the $24^2$ back in, and get

$$(5x-24)(x+24)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

An easy method is to start with factoring out $x$ and $24$

$$5x^2+96x-576=0$$
$$(5x^2-24)+(120x-576)\tag{Break into groups}$$
$$x(5x-24)+24(5x-24)\tag{Factor out x and 24}$$
$$(5x-24)(x+24)=0$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At the second line of calculations I think there is a typo, you meant $(5x^2-24x)$